# I can select from a MySQL database, but nothing happens when I run this insert (only insert into 1 table)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to insert into a table in my database, however nothing happens. Another script can write to a table, but when I run an insert query for any other table nothing happens, however I can run a fetch array query from any table. This is my code, which will not do anything, any ideas?

```
<?php
define("HOST", "localhost"); // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "*******"); // The database username.(Correct)
define("PASSWORD", "*******"); // The database password. (Correct)
define("DATABASE", "*******"); // The database name. (Correct)

$con = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

$con->query("INSERT INTO Day (Order, Day,) VALUES ('7', 'Someday')");

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: For one thing remove the last comma in `Day,`

Comment: Also, I'd imagine that you need to quote Order, as ORDER is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in SQL (used in the ORDER BY clause.) You can escape keywords with backticks in MySQL. Try ``INSERT INTO Day (`Order`, Day) VALUES ('7', 'Someday')`` Also, look into using [mysqli_error](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.mysqli-error.htm) to find out what's going wrong. It's better than guessing.

Comment: `Order` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html change it to something else. Or as Matt stated, place it inside backticks.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma in the below part after column Day:

```
$con->query("INSERT INTO Day (Order, Day,) VALUES ('7', 'Someday')");
```

Try to execute after removing it

Comment: Also, try to not name your columns as that of MySQL reserved names like Day

Comment: Also you may use mysqli_error function to get last MySQL error as string.

Example:
echo mysqli_error;

Comment: `Day` is not a reserved word. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html but `order` is.

Comment: Yes it is not, but mysql statements like "BETWEEN NOW() and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)", will confuse the users.

Comment: "Try removing it" No matter what, it MUST be removed. Even if it doesn't solve his error

Comment: @Rajesh What does `BETWEEN NOW() and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` have anything to do with the OP's code? (nothing). It's clear that the OP wants to simply insert into DB and not query in between dates. All that needs to be done is to put the word `Order` inside backticks and remove the comma after `day`. You're only saying "try and remove it" instead of giving an actual answer that will (hopefully) solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli has methods to retrieve errors, please check:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

At first glance, you have a comma here "...Day **,** ) VALUES..." that shouldn't be there.

Regards,